# For loop in vuejs like php

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

It is possible in **vuejs** to `v-for` a loop like **php**?

I want this output:

```
<select>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>0</option>
</select>
```

My code (ticket.quantity = 2):

```
<select>
    <option v-for="index in ticket.quantity" :value="index" :key="index">{{index}}</option>
</select>
```

My output:

```
<select>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to loop `ticket.quantity + 1` :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      ticket: {quantity: 2}
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <select>
    <option v-for="(q, index) in ticket.quantity + 1" :value="index" :key="index">{{index}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: this also works with [vue2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range)

Comment: @Ol D. Castor hey mate, sure, take a look at snippet again now it's vue2 :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Nikola didn't worked for me completely but I managed to solve it like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    <option v-for="index in parseInt(ticket.quantity)" :value="index" :key="index">{{index}}</option>
</select>
```